# Graphene - Can it produce a magnetic field?

Tags: magnetic-fields, graphene

So it's probably a quick no on this one, but since I haven't majored in physics or chemistry I have no idea if it's possible to make Graphene generate a magnetic field.

Assuming power or current is no problem.
Having a small PCB made out of graphene components, will they generate magnetic currents? If so, can they become strong enough that you could build a electro magnet?

What I would like to do is simply replace the copper rotor of a DC brushless motor with a 3d printed graphene disc and/or replace the stator of the motor. If graphene can generate magnetic fields this should be possible right?

I guess what I'm also asking is if it's possible to induce magnetic fields in a carbon structure such as graphene which will be used to eliminate eddy currents within the rotor.

Comment: How would this solve headaches? And what do you mean with "generate a magnetic field". If a current flows through a graphene solenoid, it will surely create a magnetic field.

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE.Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question. Thanks!

Comment: @SebastianRiese Nice, then my idea isn't hopeless after all. Might be expensive, but plausible at least.

Comment: @gonenc sorry for a badly formulated question. I'm usually more verbally potent when asking questions but this field is so new to me I thought the question was clear enough. I've update my question :)

Comment: As graphene is conducting electricity, you will not eliminate eddy currents. They are not a consequence of "metallicity" but of conductivity.

Comment: @SebastianRiese Seeing as how the most common type of rotor is built out of [individually isolated steel disks fused with a isolated aluminium squirrel cage](http://www.globalspec.com/RefArticleImages/5A7ADF06AC71D37FCF06D7AB0A3DDEDF_figure_31.gif), i'm not so concerned with the conductivity itself. It's actually to my liking in this project. So if i can replace the steel in the picture above with graphene, that would be perfect.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the motor design? (I don't fully understand the one you linked), I know motors with passive rotors (which are in modern applications neodymium magnets), motors with active rotors (and active or passive stators) and a commutator and asynchronous motors. How does your intended motor design fit in these coordinates. Furthermore I guess the point of steel in the design is that steel is ferromagnetic, graphene is not (or not in a useful way for something like this). Especially as steel would not be the material of choice where conductivity is relevant.

Comment: @SebastianRiese Not the most entertaining video but have a look at [this youtube clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LtJoJBUSe28) as it will describe the workings of the DC motor design better than i can.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exfoliated_graphite_nanoplatelets
Technically, pure sheets Should work even better. Also scouring the web looking for info on this.

Comment: Note that there is no such a thing as "magnetic current", that would imply there exist magnetic monopoles and those have not been found to date.

Answer (score 0):

yeah it should do. as long as the material is conductive, it will induce a magnetic field. the problem is that you need exfoliated graphene which is hard to produce. once mass production of it starts, it will easily replace copper solenoids.

Comment: Care to elaborate on the need for exfoliated graphene?